# How can I run a SQL statement in the background so the user don't have to wait, in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

I want SQL Server to create a pdf every time that a quotation is created in SAP Business One database. I already have a program that create the file and can run it from SQL Server (using `xp_cmdshell`), the problem is that it takes a long time to do it and SAP Business One stays frozen until it's done.

I need to execute the Pdf maker program in the background

Comment: I think you may need to provide more detailed information.

Comment: Yes, there is many options. It all depends on what you need to do with the pdf afterward.

Comment: Does SQL Server actually have to make the call? Why? SQL Server can put an item to do it in a queue table and then an operating system task (task scheduler, cron, Powershell job, what have you) can wake up every minute and process whatever's on the queue.